# Uso de la palabra clave "this" en los parámetros de un clase static extendida c#

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber porque en este pedazo de código se debe usar la palabra "this" y si es necesario utilizarlo.

```
public static class MetodosExtendidos
{
    public static string PrimeraLetraMayuscula(this string valor)
    {
        if (valor.Length > 0)
        {
            char[] array = valor.ToCharArray();
            array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
            return new string(array);
        }
        return valor;
    }

    public static string ValorNumero(this int valor)
    {
        string mivalor = "";
        switch(valor)
        {
            case 1:
                mivalor = "uno"; break;
            case 2:
                mivalor = "dos"; break;
            default:
                mivalor = "otro valor"; break;
        }
        return mivalor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El usar la palabra `this` en el primer parámetro de una función `static` (dentro de una clase `static` también) implica que ese método es un [método de extensión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), estos permiten agregar métodos a clases predefinidas, según Microsoft:

> Los métodos de extensión permiten "agregar" métodos a los tipos
>   existentes sin crear un nuevo tipo derivado, recompilar o modificar de
>   otra manera el tipo original.

En tus ejemplos, las llamadas al método serían

```
string a;
a.PrimeraLetraMayuscula();
```

En lugar de `PrimeraLetraMayuscula(a);` (si no usaras la palabra `this`)

Al igual que en el segundo ejemplo donde sería

```
int a;
a.ValorNumero();
```

En lugar de `ValorNumero(a);` (si no usaras la palabra `this`)